# Unity MiniJSON: Can't deserialize WWW response

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm sending a WWW request and getting the proper txt response in JSON, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to deserialize the JSON string into a dictionary. This is the code:

```
IEnumerator requestScores(int level)
{
    WWW jsonScores = new WWW(requestScoresURL + level);
    yield return jsonScores; //Wait for download to complete
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    while (!jsonScores.isDone)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (elapsedTime >= 10.0f) break;
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!jsonScores.isDone || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonScores.error))
    {
        Debug.LogError(string.Format("Fail Whale!\n{0}", jsonScores.error));
        yield break;
    }
    string response = jsonScores.text;
    Debug.Log(elapsedTime + " : " + response);


    // Here "search" gets null value 
    Dictionary<string, object> search = Json.Deserialize(response) as Dictionary<string, object>;

}
```

So `jsonScores.txt` is retrieved correctly as far as I can tell but `Dictionary<string,object> search` comes out as null, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what was wrong in there, as I was getting multiple rows it was needed to deserialize into a list of dictionaries instead of a single one.

This is the code that worked:

```
List <Dictionary<string, object>> list;
```

...

```
list = Json.Deserialize(response) as List<Dictionary<string, object>>;

foreach (Dictionary<string, object> row in list)
{
    // Do whatever with row
}
```